# Where is "`" key on a physical Finnish keyboard using English layout?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

My Mac-Pro uses a Finnish keyboard by "hardware". 
When I switched to the US keyboard layout, I cannot type "`" anymore.

The place where <kbd>`</kbd> usually appears (below <kbd>esc</kbd>) gives 
<kbd>§</kbd> or <kbd>±</kbd> (when <kbd>Shift</kbd> is pressed).

How to type "`" in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the key to the left of the z.